# When starting a new django project via django-admin.py is there a way to inject my own variables?

Tags: django, variables, django-admin

When starting a new Django project via `django-admin.py` is there a way to inject my own variables?

I'd like to use `{{ <my_var_name }}` so that the project is automatically setup for me.

Thanks for the help!

Casey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such capability with the django generator.

What you need is called a 'scaffolding' or 'boilerplate' generator. Usually you enter some configuration parameters (using input, conf files etc depending on the generator) and then the generator configures the new project.

A django generator that is written in python is [pyscaffold](https://github.com/blue-yonder/pyscaffold).

A very common and popular web scaffolding generator if you are slightly familiar with node.js is [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) which surprisingly offers quite a number of django project generators.

I have personally developed a generator called [django-ana](https://github.com/Wtower/generator-django-ana) but you can search for others [here](http://yeoman.io/generators/) too.

Experimenting with this is easy because it is matter of installing each generator and generating a project to see what parameters it asks and what it generates. Then pick the one closest to your interest and even open some relevant issue to ask for sth different. Or you can even play with yeoman yourself anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary variables, nope.

The [current wording](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#startproject) is deceptively specific:

> The template context used is:
>
> Any option passed to the startproject command **(among the command’s
>   supported options)**
>
> ...

Here is a brief [discussion that lead to that doc change](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18277) and the feature has not been discussed since then as far as I can tell.